# Saves new feature notifier is acting weird in the review queue on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review, responsive-design

I just opened up Meta.SE on my phone, and decided to take a peek at the review queues. The Close Votes queue had a red dot, so I decided to check it out.

I was greeted with this:

[image: The Close Votes queue with a new feature notification about Saves half visible at the top of the page]

(Yes, ironically, the question in the queue is about Bookmarks / Saves.)

Scrolling down, this box (which, incidentally, I believe I already dismissed on a different site) stayed half off the top of the page:

[image: Screenshot of the queue, now scrolled down to the comments, with the notifier still half off the top of the page]

This is rather annoying and most likely shouldn't be happening. This Saves notification probably should only be shown on question pages and not be shown in the queue at all.

Comment: Solution: don't review on a mobile device. ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Nah... not everyone has access to a computer 24/7

Comment: I didn't fact the exact issue, but scrolling the page with the notifier open was weird.

Comment: Even on desktop, the notifier is pretty annoying IMO. It partially hides the question content, so I need to dismiss it before going on. Also, as you briefly mention, it pops up on every subsite even when logged in, which is particularly annoying when reading through HNQ.

Comment: @konst not pretty, very annoying. I was very surprised though to see it goes away on its own after several reloads, without having to dismiss it.

Comment: Hello, a fix has been deployed to remove the popover from review queues. Please let me know if you're able to confirm that you no longer see it. You may need to test the review queue on another site to confirm. Thank you!

Comment: Related: [iPhone push notifications - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394972/iphone-push-notifications)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update Oct 17**: A fix has been deployed to remove the popover from review queues.

---

The Saves popover/feature notifier has been disabled on all sites except for Stack Overflow. It will still appear for someone who hasn't dismissed it yet but once dismissed it shouldn't appear again on review queues. We will look into options for limiting the popover to certain pages and areas of the site. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 6):

I agree, a user who finds their way into the review queues:

- Didn't enter the queues aiming to find high quality info to revisit later.
- Reviewers are likely site savvy and wouldn't need the *Saves* reminder to begin with.
- Is likely busy thinking about how to action review items - so lets not distract them.

Altogether the questions listings seem like the right place to display the popup. Disabling the popup in the review queues might actually save some work over fixing the design issue.