# iPhone push notifications

Tags: discussion, notifications, mobile-safari, ios, iphone

**What are the current methods to get push notifications on the iPhone?**

I am looking for something that would **display a badge or a banner on the iPhone when someone posts an answer to my question or a comment on my post.**

Yes, like an app. Of course, I know that the Stack Exchange apps are long dead. What do you use instead as a method for letting you know of the Stack Exchange activity, **without** opening the Stack Exchange page in the iPhone browser?

My current workaround is to use the badges and banners of the Gmail app on my iPhone, but this informs me of any new emails, while I am looking only for the notifications from Stack Exchange.

When posting an answer, please:

- **Post the complete solution**, for example if it involves an RSS feed, then include in the answer your suggested app for notifications from this RSS feeds.
- Preferably, the solution should include an **easy way to set up notifications from all stacks**. For example, there should be no need to enter one URL feed per stack for each of the multiple stacks, such as one for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and another one for [Politics Stack Exchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), etc.

**See also:**

- [Is/could the "Android/iOS" application endpoint for notifications be opened up to other apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372921/578690)

> My backup plan for that: have my server login to a Stack Exchange site directly and monitor the inbox WebSocket, and use another app to send the push notifications. Probably with some filter to suppress non-urgent messages... But I hope Stack Exchange will implement web push notifications before that happens. (*Glorfindel*)

- [Now that the mobile apps are no longer in development ... Could we get Web Push Notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321093/578690)

> Based on our current roadmap, this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. (*Anita Taylor*)

- [Updated: Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/578690)

> For push notifications, there's no replacement yet. (*Glorfindel*)

Comment: Frankly - the company is more interested in 'wasting' time on things like AI and trying to reinvent the wheel than features that benefit engagement by advanced users like this.

Comment: Look at https://stackapps.com. You might post an app request / suggestion there. -> [Is Stack Apps the place to suggest applications?](https://stackapps.com/q/980/105187). Another challenge is to motivate people to participate there.

Comment: I vaguely recall one of the third party apps for ios (crew) might do push notifications. Being an android user, there's no way for me to confirm tho

Comment: Aren't there RSS feeds for such things?

Comment: Maybe not. *[What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its)*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum there's no RSS feed for the inbox notifications, so it's not very relevant anyway. Only way is by using the API, and there's no "SE API Reader" out of the box, someone has to write it from scratch.

Comment: `http://stack exchange site/feeds/user/user id/responses`

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum nice find, and this is worthy of its own answer. Also, this might reveal a privacy leak, I might start a bug report soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the user This_is_NOT_a_forum mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394972/iphone-push-notifications?noredirect=1#comment1320569_394972), there is RSS feed showing the latest responses:

```
http://stack exchange site/feeds/user/user id/responses
```

So with this at hand, you can look for "RSS reader push notifications" app, hook it to the above feed, and you have push notifications for the responses on your phone.

For example, OP of this question found [NetNewsWire](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/netnewswire-rss-reader/id1480640210) to be helpful, but there are probably others as well.

Comment: See also: [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its) - credit goes to *This_is_NOT_a_forum*.

Comment: Tested on iPhone 15, iOS 17.1.2, and this method works OK with these apps: [NetNewsWire: Free and Open Source RSS Reader for Mac and iOS](https://netnewswire.com/) and [Unread: An RSS Reader](https://www.goldenhillsoftware.com/unread/). Of course, there may be other apps (not tested).

Comment: Note that you will need to set up a separate RSS feed for every Stack you watch (if you are active on several of them). Not a show-stopper, but just clarifying this.

Comment: @TimurShtatland regarding the separate RSS feed for every Stack yeah, each site has its own feed and SE inbox unify them all, sadly no network wide RSS feed. But maybe worth asking for one? :)